# Detox by.id is not a function

Tags: detox

I'm working on my first test using detox but got the following problem:

[image: Detox code]

Please help me.

Comment: Please post your code as text and not as an image. This doesn't make sense. What is `by` in your context? As you can read in the error message `id` is not a function. So you can't call it like `.id()` or something. You can use `console.log(by);` and check in your dev tools what attributes this object (if it's one) has.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, being a wrapper over common JS test-runners such as Mocha and Jest, when Detox fails to initialize in (i.e. in the `beforeAll()`) it is forced to move forward to nevertheless try to run all tests in the suite. Also, without proper initializaion, global objects such as `by`, `device` and even `detox` do net get registered. Hence the error.

What matters in your case is for you to scroll and find the *first* error provided by Detox' logs. That should give you a hint of what really went wrong.

In any case, your tests will not run without proper initialization, and the inclusion of init code in the path for the test runner. Be sure to thoroughly go over [the setup guide](https://github.com/wix/Detox/blob/master/docs/Introduction.GettingStarted.md) and its references.